# Запрос разрешений, когда пользователь нажал "Больше не спрашивать"

Tags: java, android, permissions

По нажатию на определённую кнопку (например, "Определить местоположение") приложение запрашивает нужные разрешения у пользователя. Соответственно, он может принять, отклонить или отклонить и запретить спрашивать в дальнейшем. Если будет выбран последний вариант, то такое окошко с запросом разрешений уже не будет появляться. Так как сообщать об отсутствии разрешений и предоставлять возможность их дать всё равно нужно, то в случае отсутствия нужных разрешений я вывожу настроенное мной диалоговое окно с текстом вроде "Нажмите сюда, чтобы перейти в настройки и дать нужные разрешения". Только вот если пользователь ещё не нажал "Больше не показывать", то одновременно выскакивает и системное окошко с запросом разрешений и сделанное мной диалоговое окно. **Собственно вопрос:** как проверять, нажал ли пользователь "Больше не показывать" и выскакивает ли у него системное окошко с запросом или нет? Чтобы показывать свой диалог только в случае, если пользователь не увидит прямой запрос разрешений. Или же в таких случаях делается как-то по-другому? Может вообще можно убрать пункт "Больше не показывать" из системного окошка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Может вообще можно убрать пункт "Больше не показывать" из системного окошка?

Нет.

> как проверять, нажал ли пользователь "Больше не показывать" и выскакивает ли у него системное окошко с запросом или нет?

Вы можете проверить методом [shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat#shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String)) в своем onRequestPermissionsResult.

P.S. Для того чтобы узнать поставил ли пользователь галочку "Больше не спрашивать", нужно вызывать данный метод в `onRequestPermissionsResult`, а не перед проверкой разрешений. Иначе он будет возвращать `false` и при первом запросе разрешения.

Comment: данный метод возвращает false не только когда пользователь нажал "Больше не спрашивать", но и в случае, если запрос разрешений выполняется впервые, как отследить этот момент?

Comment: @all_possible вызывайте данный метод в onRequestPermissionsResult. В таком случае он будет вызываться только, если пользователь поставил галочку "Больше не спрашивать"

Comment: @all_possible дополнил ответ

Comment: теперь после того, как пользователь нажимает "Больше не спрашивать" ему тут же выскакивает моё диалоговое окно, думаю это нехорошо, можно ли как-то решить?

Comment: @all_possible это уже вопрос реализации. Можно решить через доп параметр. Вообще, модальное окно решение неудачное. Лучше выводить текст о том, что разрешение еще не получено на самой странице. Например, посмотрите как сделано в инстаграм, попробуйте добавить сторис предварительно отключив разрешение.  И не мучайтесь с модалками.

Answer (score 1):

Я использую библиотеку https://github.com/florent37/RuntimePermission

Пример использования такой:

```
RuntimePermission(requireActivity())
    .onResponse {
        if (it.foreverDenied.isNotEmpty())
            /*Отображаем диалог с переходом в настройки*/
    }
    .request(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) // например, камера
    .onAccepted { /*разрешение получено*/ }
    .onDenied { /*разрешение не получено*/ }
    .ask()
```

Answer (score 1):

Google разработал специальные [правила](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) запроса "опасных" разрешений которые обязан(!) соблюдать разработчик.

Разберем их вкратце.

1. При начале работы вы анализируете есть ли у вас нужное разрешение методом `checkSelfPermission`, если есть, то продолжаете штатную работу приложения.
2. Далее вы анализируете, а не отклонил ли пользователь уже первое предложение в стандартном диалоге системы методом `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale`.
3. Если нет, то вы запрашиваете разрешение методом `checkSelfPermission`.
4. Если да, то вы понимаете, что у вас остался только один шанс получить нужное разрешение и показываете пользователю диалоговое окно (или делаете это иным способом) с подробным описанием зачем и почему вам нужно данное разрешение. Диалог содержит также 2 кнопки: "Запрос разрешения" и "Отмена" (или "Нет спасибо не надо"). Через диалог происходит повторный запрос на получение разрешения.
5. Результаты запроса приходят в перегруженный метод `onRequestPermissionsResult` и в случае успеха вы разблокируете необходимые для работы элементы интерфейса.

Все! Нельзя больше пользователю навязывать какие-то предложения и тем более перекрывать экран диалоговым окном с надписью "идите за разрешением туда", то есть речь идет о деликатном отношении к пользователю.

Comment: Это все замечательно работает ровно до тех пор, пока ВЕСЬ функционал приложения не оказывается завязан на какое-то разрешение. Если Вы пишете приложение-камеру, то Вы не сможете работать без разрешения на камеру и пользователю это как-то надо объяснять.

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov Зачем вы мне пытаетесь что-то доказать? Это не мои правила, но я с ними согласен.

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov Есть пункт 4, где вам дается шанс объяснить, что камера без разрешения на камеру - приложение так себе по функционалу. К тому же нужно быть альтернативно-одаренным, чтобы не давать разрешение камеры для приложения-камеры.